# Set a limit in the results (no mysql)

Tags: php, limit

Can I put a limit to show in a list of images extracted from a folder? I should point out that I do not mean with mysql but simple php.

Practically from a folder I extract all the images, here, I would like to set a limit. is it possible? or must necessarily the database?

Comment: Can you please post your so far efforts?

Comment: I have not made any changes, just wanted to know a guide or a php code to do this.

Comment: you can use the http://www.datatables.net/ , it limits the display result,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention "extracted from a folder" and also "or must necessarily the database" so I'm not sure what your source is.

If you are getting the list of images them from a folder, presumably using something like glob() or readdir() or scandir() then you end up with an array. If you only want to display a certain number of those images then simply stop after that number of iterations...

```
$imgs = glob('*.jpg');
$count = 0;
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    if ($count++ > 20) break; // place a limit of 20
    echo "<img src='$img' alt='$img' />\n";
}
```

If you are using a database to obtain your list of image filenames then you would do something similar, controlling it within your loop:

```
$sql = "SELECT filename, alt_text FROM ...";
$conx = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname, ...);
$results = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
$count = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conx, $results)) {
    if ($count++ > 20) break; // place a limit of 20
    echo "<img src='$row[filename]' alt='$row[alt_text]' />\n";
}
mysqli_free_results($results);
```

If I have not yet answered your question then please clarify. If I have, please vote for the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I have use this: if ($count++ > 20) break; // place a limit of 20 in my code. Thank!

Comment: If that answers your question, could you please mark it as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
array_slice(scandir($dir), 0, $limit);
```